# Android: How to calculate progress percentage for multiple files upload

Tags: android, upload, progress-bar, percentage

I am uploading files from android to server, I am doing the upload with progress percentage overall for all files from 0 to 100%. All the files are uploading one by one. The known things are

- Total number of files
- Total bytes for single file
- Transferred bytes of single file
- Total number of uploaded files

I have a single progressbar to show overall percentage for all.

The uploading code is:

```
public abstract class UploadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>
{
    private Context mContext;
    private Cursor mCursor;
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    private int mItemCounter;
    private int mFilesCount;
    private int mUploaded;
    private long mTotalSize;

    public UploadTask(Context context, Cursor cursor, ProgressBar progressBar)
    {
        mContext = context;
        mCursor = cursor;
        mProgressBar = progressBar;            
        mFilesCount = cursor.getCount();            
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mProgressBar.setMax(mFilesCount);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpContext httpContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        while (mCursor.moveToNext())
        {
            String path = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("_data"));                
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://...");
            try
            {
                CustomMultiPartEntity multipartContent = new CustomMultiPartEntity(new CustomMultiPartEntity.ProgressListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void transferred(long num)
                    {
                        publishProgress((int) (((((float) mUploaded) + ((float) num / (float) mTotalSize)) / (float) mFilesCount)));
                    }
                });
                multipartContent.addPart("userfile", new FileBody(new File(path), Utility.removeExtention(title), type, "UTF-8"));
                mTotalSize = multipartContent.getContentLength();
                httpPost.setEntity(multipartContent);
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, httpContext);
                InputStream inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
                StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                try
                {
                    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        total.append(line);
                    }
                    inputStream.close();
                    bufferedReader.close();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Log.wtf("response", total.toString() + " File Size: " + (mTotalSize / (1024)) + "KB");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mUploaded++;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress)
    {
        super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
        mProgressBar.setProgress(progress[0]);            
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s)
    {            
        onCompleted(s == null);
    }

    protected abstract void onCompleted(boolean result);
}
```

Comment: Okay. So what's the problem? Include a *minimal* test-case showing the issue and explain what "is wrong" or "doesn't work".

Comment: @user2864740 Its not working properly in all scenarios. I have checked it on 5, 50, 250 and more images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mProgressBar.setMax(mFilesCount);`. If you do that then you should use mFilesDownloaded in publishProgress. Otherwise start with mTotalBytesOfAllFiles and update with mTotalBytesUploaded.